What type of threshold should I buy to replace the one that goes to my garage?
I have a door threshold in my new old house that's bent and dinged up. I want to replace it, but it seems like most thresholds aren't designed for this steep of a dropoff. It's 31" wide. Is there a better/ideal solution for this other than just using a rounded threshold like they had here?
Pix of the dropoff and the bent up existing threshold plate:



if the foreground shows an indoor floor covering and the trim is fitted against a closed door, then I'd suggest that the reason it's graunched is that it's mounted the wrong way round.

There is a huge selection of thresholds at place like Home Depot and others. If it is to long just cut it with a saw (metal blade). Take the old one with you to the store for best match.

Source

Were this my home I'd be doing one of two things to eliminate the awkward drop under the threshold:

Attach a pressure-treated two-by lumber block to the face of the concrete. I'd cut it to fit the height of the concrete and the width of the outer door trim, and I'd install it with the milled edge upward to retain a nice corner radius. I'd use either concrete screws or expansion anchors and construction adhesive or silicone caulk. (You could even add a nosing of another 2x4 to thicken it further. Well screwed to the first, full-height board it'll be plenty solid.)

Build a full landing of either one or three standard stair treads deep. This can simply be a 2x4 box with 3/4" plywood on top and short posts to suit. I'd leave the plywood extending about 1 inch over the framing on the front and maybe the sides as a nosing.


By doing that you make it easier to fit any threshold you choose, you reduce the chance of future damage, and you eliminate the trip/snag hazard that exists now with that edge protruding.

Not sure why the DV on a perfectly functional, reasonable and well-formatted answer.

I didn't DV, and IMO no harm done with a thorough approach but maybe #2 seems a little scopey creepy.

Get a small discard from a stone yard.  Granite, marble, whatever.  Hopefully you can find something that matches the ceramic tile and already has a polished edge.  Maybe even for free. Cut it to fit the threshold exactly without protruding over the edge of the concrete.   If it leaves a gap, screw a brush to the bottom of the door.
